# attach screenshots to cucumber html report for passed as well as for failed scenarios in cypress 10

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

How to attach screenshots to cucumber html report for passed as well as for a failed scenarios test cases in cypress version 10

Answer (score -1):

In version 12 of "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor," you can use HTML reports integration, adding the code below.
In the file *.cypress-cucumber-preprocessorrc.json* or *package.json*
This report has the feature of adding screenshots when the test fails automatically.

**.cypress-cucumber-preprocessorrc.json** *(assure to have created this file in the root of your project)*

```
{
    "html": {
            "enabled": true,
            "output": "path/report.html"
    }
}
```

For more information visit  https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/html-report.md

Comment: This answer does not solve the question.
he emphasizes that his test cases are "successful". this is explicitly mentioned in the documentation.

https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/json-report.md